# Using Apache Common's MultiKeyMap concurrently

Tags: java, apache-commons

In Apache Common's MultiKeyMap javadoc, I see the following entry:

> **Note that MultiKeyMap is not synchronized and is not thread-safe.** If
>   you wish to use this map from multiple threads concurrently, you must
>   use appropriate synchronization. This class may throw exceptions when
>   accessed by concurrent threads without synchronization.

What's not clear to me is if this is just referring to just concurrent modification, or if using the `get` method concurrently even without calling `put` would cause problem as well. Intuition tells me that just calling `get` shouldn't do anything that'd modify the inner collection, and so that should be safe, but I just want to make sure.